# change google datastore to Firestore in the same application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore

I have used google Datastore in my application and I want to migrate to Google Firestore. I keep getting this error message

> This project uses another database service ... Your current project is set up to use Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode. You can access data for this project from the Cloud Datastore console.

I have tried to disable the Cloud Datastore API, but with no success.
is there a way to change to firestore ?

I cant change to another project because I have customers who already installed the application with the old firebase project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you cannot switch from Datastore to Firestore in the same project.

Having said that, some time after Cloud Firestore is released for general availability, Google will begin contacting owners of existing Cloud Datastore databases to schedule an automatic upgrade to Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode. If you have an application that uses Cloud Datastore, you will not need to update your application code and the upgrade will not require downtime.

You can find more info about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/upgrade-to-firestore).